# Returned event object overwriting parent object - javascript, easeljs

Tags: javascript, oop, easeljs, createjs

I am using easeljs for a HTML5 game.

I am calling onClick from within a method in a class, but the event object is overwriting my 'this' object so I can no longer access the other class methods or vars. For example I have something like (obviously this is not the actual code, just a quick illustration):

```
function Book(){

  this.text = "this is the text";

  this.makeText = function(){
            //Define some shapes
            var character = new Container();
            character.addChild(some shapes);
            character.onClick = this.detectClick;
  }

  this.detectClick = function(){
           alert(this.text);
  }
}
```

So, if I run this, I would get an undefined alert because in my detectClick method, this is now my event object.

So how do I call the original text from within this method?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to us closure to pass the object reference

```
 var self = this;
 character.onClick = function(){ self.detectClick() };
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use a simple proxy method.

```
function proxy(method, scope) {
    return function() {
        return method.apply(scope, params);
    }
}
character.onclick = proxy(detectClick, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok that you really need to do is

```
function Book(){

  this.text = "this is the text";

  this.makeText = function(){
            //Define some shapes
            var character = new Container();
            character.addChild(some shapes);
            character.onClick = this.detectClick.bind(this);
  }

  this.detectClick = function(){
           alert(this.text);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

scope  of  `'this'`  is the problem in your code. Change your code like the below code

```
 function Book(){

  this.text = "this is the text";
  var that=this;
  this.makeText = function(){
        //Define some shapes
        var character = new Container();
        character.addChild(some shapes);
        character.onClick = that.detectClick;
 }

 this.detectClick = function(){
       alert(this.text);
 }
}
```